# How to compile and run c++ program from Kate editor using build tool?

Tags: c++, kate

I'm trying to compile and run a c++ program from Kate editor with the following build command.

```bsh
konsole -e g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -c %f -o %n.o && chmod +x %n.o && ./%n.o
```

But it gives me the error "Exec format error". How to resolve this?

Comment: That looks like a `g++` usage error rather than an issue with the Kate build tool - see for example [Exec format error of gcc-compiled Hello World c++](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696764/exec-format-error-of-gcc-compiled-hello-world-c)

Comment: Yes, that was for the -c flag. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have hello.cpp as our example c++ file. you can run through kate by pressing "F4" and writing the below commands.

g++ hello.cpp -o hello

./hello